How can we have a specific theme to the page which opens up when users click on collection public link
How can we have a specific theme to the page which opens up when users click on collection public link.
Currently default theme gets applied.but requirement is this public link page should not display the logo.

Public link for the collection uses the default theme set inside your Content hub tenant. Therefore if a user changes or modifies the current default theme, the change is automatically applied to the collection public link page as well.
You can add below css inside your default theme to hide the logo.
.public-collections-body #main-menu{
    display: none;
}

This will hide the logo only on the collection public link page. You can find more details here on the theme applied on public link for collection.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thanks for the help Let me try this

Working as expected thanks
